# Unable to mount 2TB NTFS hard drive in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, mount, ntfs, ubuntu-14.04

Can somebody assist me on this one?

```
Error mounting /dev/sdg4 at /media/jote/DATA_4: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdg4" "/media/jote/DATA_4"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: Error reading bootsector: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdg4': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

I asked [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502578/unable-to-mount-large-ntfs-drive) on AskUbuntu and got the answer to use Windows's chkdsk /f to repair the 'corrupted' NTFS partitions. However, my partition is perfectly healthy! Can someone explain me why a tool like PartedMagic - which is also Linux - can perfectly mount and use this drive and Ubuntu 14.04 cannot?

Comment: And have you run `chkdsk /f` -> reboot -> `chkdsk /f` as it says? (The reboot isn't strictly necessary, but it re-settles Windows)

Comment: Please use **<pre>** before and **</pre>** after your error message text - it makes it readable in comparision to what is above.

Comment: Check NTFS driver versions, on Windows and when you can and cannot use the drive - Do they match? Which versions do you see/use?

Comment: @BigChris: I ran chkdsk /f and rebooted into Windows twice, as said in the error message.

Comment: @Hannu : Thank you for the advice. Indeed, it looks better now!

Comment: @Hannu : I never had problems using it on Windows. PartedMagic (Linux) mounts and uses it without complaining, but I don't know what driver it uses. Ubuntu 14.04 has the latest ntfs-3g driver and can't mount it by no means. I have two 1Tb ntfs harddisks that covered the same route as the 2Tb, and Ubuntu kindly mounts them. Could it be that the 2Tb is simply too large for Ubuntu?

Comment: You have to investigate that yourself, and `the latest` doesn't mean it `has no bugs`. I do not use NTFS in Linux, other than for transferring files - occasionally. I have several 3TB disks (using ext4 fs) and they have not malfunctioned in any way. I see several entries here and elsewhere about Linux-NTFS not being quite relieable. What there is causing it is much harder to tell.

Comment: For what it is worth: I think you lost some linefeeds in your text ;-) - it could look even better WITH them.

Comment: Ahh... forgot to say: the `version numbers` of your drivers will allow you to google up RELEVANT information - for that specific driver. Even a _very small difference_ in the version name may be significant.

Comment: @Hannu : Most likely there's a bug in the driver Ubuntu uses, but my computer knowledge is to weak to find that out the way you said. I think I'm going to ask AskUbuntu to submit the issue to a developer; they will probably refuse but I can always try. Thank you very much for trying to help me out!

Comment: I edited your post in order to make it more readable (in par to what you have on AskUbuntu). With this being said, cross-posting is usually frowned upon the community, as it then both communities have to clean up your question.

Comment: Also, the reasons Hannu pointed are probably valid: the NTFS file system is proprietary and as such no implementation outside of Microsoft will include every little detail needed to make it run as well as in Microsoft. There are different implementations, which may be why PartedMagic works whilst the default Ubuntu drivers don't.

Comment: @Doktoro : Thank you for cleaning up my mess; I'm totally new to this kind of forums and not yet familiar with the layout stuff, I apologize for that. Also I will regard your answer as the final one answering my question, guess I'll just have to use Windows if I want to use that drive, won't bother you guys with this problem any longer.

Comment: There may be other reasons that would explain your problem. You have only asked this question 2 days ago; maybe no one that can answer your question has showed up so far. A good place to start understanding how this site works is to read the [about].

Answer (score 1):

Install ntfs-3g with `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`.
Then run the ntfsfix command on your NTFS partition.

> ntfsfix v2.0.0 (libntfs 10:0:0)
>
> Usage: ntfsfix [options] device
>
> ```
> Attempt to fix an NTFS partition.
>
> -h, --help             Display this help
> -V, --version          Display version information
> ```
>
> For example: ntfsfix /dev/hda6
>
> Developers' email address:
>   linux-ntfs-dev@lists.sf.net Linux NTFS
>   homepage: http://www.linux-ntfs.org

=======================================

You can use a program called ntfsprogs.  If its not installed, you can install it by, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
```

Once installed, you need to find out you NTFS drive name, just do `sudo fdisk -`l, to find that out, once you know the name, then

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXX
```

Make sure that you replace the XX with your drive's name.

**Note**: Whenever you're dealing with partition, make sure that you have a complete backup just to be on the safe side.

===================================

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

Then run it:

```
sudo testdisk
```

and follow the instructions. You must search for partitions and then write the changes.

Thanks to answerers here:

- [Fix corrupt NTFS partition without Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47700/fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-without-windows)
- [Repair NTFS without Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330733/repair-ntfs-without-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved from a Windows PC using the "chkdsk" command.
https://neosmart.net/wiki/chkdsk/

Windows will automatically repair the corrupted file system.

It works :D